# Detecting an html attribute's value with a userscript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, userscripts

I am trying to make myself a personal user script, but I need to detect an html attribute's value. For example:

```
<div id="a">Stuff</div>
    <div id="b" value="false"></div>
```

How could I create an if statement in the script, that triggers if the "value" attribute of element b turns to true?

Comment: what is a userscript? Do you perhaps mean javascript or Jquery. Or are you unaware of these names? or is there actually something called userscript which i have just never heard of?

Comment: A user script is a tampermonkey or greasemonkeyscript

Comment: A `<div>` doesn't, and shouldn't, have a `value` attribute; and since this JavaScript, regardless of it being a user-script, you'd write it exactly the same way as in "regular" JavaScript. So, where are you stuck?

Comment: I got it to work, yes, I know a user script is JavaScript, but it's client sided. I needed a way to call an attribute value, but apparently I'm blind and JQuery supports it.

Comment: Anything that jQuery can do JavaScript must, by definition, be able to do. Please, explain your problem more clearly in order that it can be understood. Because it doesn't matter where the script is run, so long as it's executed (which it will be, if it's properly called).

Comment: @DavidThomas agreed-ed and up-voted comment. DaFudgeWizzad See answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = document.getElementById("b");

if(element != null) {
    if (element.value  == "true") {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Try with this:  `function test() {
  
 element = document.getElementById("b").getAttribute("value")
 
 if(element == "true") {
  // if element == true
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "true";
 } else {
  // if element == false
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "false";
 }   
}` @DaFudgeWizzad

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link... it says that you can import JQuery into your userscript.

[youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctTt9a6VMuE)

You can then get the value of any attrubute using jquery API for attr

[Jquery Api attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

which can be done like

```
var bAttrValue = $("#b").attr("value");
```

You then coulld write a function which takes in an Id and an attribute like

```
function GetAttributeValue(elemId, attribute)
{
    //Todo: write checks to ensure the elemId exists and that it as the attribute;
    var elemAttrValue = $("#"+elemId).attr(attribute);
    return elemAttrValue;
}
```

You could then consume it like

```
var DivbValue = GetAttributeValue("b", "value")
if(DivbValue) //true
{
    //do something
}
else //false
{
    //do something
}
```

alternatively write this in JavaScript

```
function GetAttributeValue(elemId, attribute)
{
    //Todo: write checks to ensure the elemId exists and that it as the attribute;
    element = document.getElementById(elemId);
    return element[attribute];
}
```